# Jackson error handling

Tags: java, error-handling, jackson

Used version of jackson: 2.3.0

I have following code

```
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            MenuItem[] menuItems = mapper.readValue(result, MenuItem.class);
            return menuItems;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.error("Exception while parsing json", e);
        }
```

POJO

```
public class MenuItem {
    public String dataUrl;
}
```

JSON

```
 [{
            "dataUrl": ""
        },
        {
            "dataUrl": []
        }]
```

This is really simplified example to the bone, bear in mind I have zero control over the json. Above json doesnt parse, most likely the String deserializer cannot handle the array, at least that would be pretty logical.

Following expcetion occurs: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token

The question is how to achieve that what ever problem happens in one item in the json (if the json is valid) it just skips that one item but parse the others. Right now any problem just cause to not parse anything. I am aware of the annotations to ignore unknown properties but  there is banch of different problems that can happen, and in my case happens and they just at the end result in a blank page instead of page with 5% of content missing.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to write your own Deserializer class which will only process the data if it is of type text like below:

```
public class MenuItemDeserializer {
@Override
public MenuItem deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser,
                            DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
    try {
        jsonParser.nextToken();
        String dataUrl = jsonParser.getText();
        […]

        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(dataUrl);
        return menuItem;
    } catch (JsonParseException jpe) {
        [...]
    }
}

}
```

This is a custom try since I have not worked with Jackson since long time an I might have forgotten some guidelines so hope it helps.
BR.

Comment: Thanks, that might work but in case you have hundrets of objects in your model, to write such parser for each of them is a bit tedious, there has to be some general solution, I would expect even some really simple one like a flag set somewhere, I just cannot find it.